# Render to 3D texture webgl2

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, glsl, webgl

I read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webgl-dev-list/kDPaWgwg8XA) that it should be possible to render to a 3D texture in WebGL2 by using multiple render targets and attaching each layer of the 3d texture as a layer to the render target.

However I can't seem to get it to work, no errors but the values of the texture doesn't change between the reads and is just empty. The texture has `gl.RGBA8` as internal format, `gl.RGBA` as format and a size of `64x64x64`

What am I doing wrong? This is what I tried so far (pseudo code):

```
this.fbo = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.fbo);
gl.TEXTURE_3D, this.my3DTexture, 0);

this.renderBuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, this.renderBuffer);
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 64, 64);    
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, this.renderBuffer);

if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
  alert("FBO not complete!");
}

gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

this.shader.activate();

// Set uniforms ...

for (let i = 0; i < 64; i += 8) {
  gl.framebufferTextureLayer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, this.my3DTexture, 0, 0 + i);
  gl.framebufferTextureLayer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, this.my3DTexture, 0, 1 + i);
  gl.framebufferTextureLayer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, this.my3DTexture, 0, 2 + i);
  gl.framebufferTextureLayer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT3, this.my3DTexture, 0, 3 + i);
  gl.framebufferTextureLayer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT4, this.my3DTexture, 0, 4 + i);
  gl.framebufferTextureLayer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT5, this.my3DTexture, 0, 5 + i);
  gl.framebufferTextureLayer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT6, this.my3DTexture, 0, 6 + i);
  gl.framebufferTextureLayer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT7, this.my3DTexture, 0, 7 + i);

  gl.drawBuffers([
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT3,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT4,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT5,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT6,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT7,
  ]);

  let data = new Uint8Array(64*64 * 4);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 64, 64, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
  console.log("before", data);

  // Render scene
  scene.objects.forEach(object => {
    this._renderObject(object, scene, camera);
  });

  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 64, 64, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
  console.log("after one iteration read", data);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es            
precision highp float;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 layer0;
layout(location = 1) out vec4 layer1;
layout(location = 2) out vec4 layer2;
layout(location = 3) out vec4 layer3;
layout(location = 4) out vec4 layer4;
layout(location = 5) out vec4 layer5;
layout(location = 6) out vec4 layer6;
layout(location = 7) out vec4 layer7;

void main() {
    layer0 = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    layer1 = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    layer2 = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    layer3 = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    layer4 = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    layer5 = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    layer6 = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    layer7 = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
}
```

**UPDATE**: It works with `gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` but fails with `gl.TEXTURE_3D` Why? In the tests [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/blob/master/sdk/tests/conformance2/renderbuffers/framebuffer-texture-layer.html)  they are certainly attaching a layer of a 3d texture.

Comment: texture array got layers not sure if that applies to rendering to 3D textures too as for using them it does not... but I am not using webgl ...

Comment: @Spektre I first thought so too, but then I found this: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/blob/master/sdk/tests/conformance2/renderbuffers/framebuffer-texture-layer.html that actually attaches a layer of the 3D texture in one of their tests

Comment: Hi, did you managed to make it work, finally? I'm seeking some working example how to render to 3D texture with WebGL.

Comment: you didn't call `gl.drawArrays`?

Answer (score 3):

AFAICT in your sample you just needed to call `gl.drawArrays`

Your sample though is trying to render to 8 layers. WebGL2 only requires 4 layers to be supported. You can check if 8 are supported by calling `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_DRAW_BUFFERS)` so that could be another reason you code was failing.

Not required according to the spec but possibly required anyway is making the texture *texture complete*, which means make it renderable (even though we are not rendering with it we are rendering to it). In this case because I didn't make mips I set the `TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `LINEAR` since by default it's `NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` which requires mips otherwise the texture is not renderable. *not renderable* = *not usable* period in at least some drivers in the past.

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext("webgl2");
  if (!gl) {
    return alert('need webgl2');
  }
  
  const vs = `#version 300 es
  void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;
  }
  `;
  const fs = `#version 300 es
  precision mediump float;
  out vec4 outColor[4];
  void main() {
    outColor[0] = vec4(.1, .2, .3, .4);
    outColor[1] = vec4(.5, .6, .7, .8);
    outColor[2] = vec4(.9, 1., .11, .22);
    outColor[3] = vec4(.33, .44, .55, .66);
  }
  `;
  
  const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
  
  const width = 4;
  const height = 4;
  const depth = 4;
  const tex = gl.createTexture(gl.TEXTURE_3D);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_3D, tex);
  gl.texImage3D(gl.TEXTURE_3D, 0, gl.RGBA8, width, height, depth, 0,
                gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  
  const numAttachments = 4;
  const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
  for (let i = 0; i < numAttachments; ++i) {
    gl.framebufferTextureLayer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i, tex, 0, i);
  }
  
  gl.drawBuffers([
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, 
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, 
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT3,
  ]);
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < numAttachments; ++i) {
    gl.readBuffer(gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i);
    const pixel = new Uint8Array(4);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
    console.log('layer:', i, '=', Array.from(pixel).map(v => (v / 255).toFixed(2)).join(', '));
  }
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was trying exactly the same thing as you and finally succeeded, just to note some caveats for future readers.

2 things that don't work with `TEXTURE_3D` (as of Chrome 84):

1. Binding a depth buffer to the framebuffer will screw things up, I even got browser glitches for doing this, no matter it's a single texture or texture array. So if you'd like to use `TEXTURE_3D`, do NOT bind any depth buffer.
2. No float texture, which you didn't use, but it failed me so hard that I want to point it out.

If the above requirement is necessary, you might as well stick to `gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`